# .get function with an opened file stream in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, fileinputstream

I have an open input file stream. It is able to open the other file (a txt file) successfully. And by making adjustments to the code right below I can get it read and output the other txt file (all ASCII characters, just letters) just fine. However, I was playing around with the below function. This results in one line being read, when there are in fact three lines. I want to know **why**. The size of the array is not the problem, i.e., making it larger does not seem to fix anything.

```
void DispFile(fstream& iFile)
{
     auto char fileChar[256];

     while (inFile.get(fileChar,256))
           {                                 

            cout << fileChar;

           }

}
```

Here is the code that WORKS:

```
void DispFile(fstream& iFile)
{
   auto char fileChar[256];


   while (inFile.getline(fileChar,256))
   {
   cout << fileChar;
   cout << endl;
   }
}
```

OR

```
void DispFile(fstream& iFile)
{

   char file;

   while (inFile.get(file)
   {
   cout << file;
   }

}
```

So why does using inFile.get(array, dimension) result in only one line being read, while the others work like a charm (so to speak).

Comment: The code that you have seems fine.  What do you mean by "only one line is getting read?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first version the `.get(array,size)` extracts characters until the delimiting characters. By default this is a newline, '\n'. However once reaches this character, it does not extract it from the input stream but leaves it for the next input attempt. Therefore the next time you call `get()` it will find the newline from the previous `get()` and immediately stop.

The `.getline()` works because it extracts the newline and the `.get` works because it simply gets each character one at a time until the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

get(char*, int) reads until the deliminator ('\n') but does not extract it - so it gets "stuck" on it.  getline removes it.